# Celery connecting to rabbitmq-server instead of redis-server

Tags: django, celery, background-process, redis-server

I have a Django application which I want to configure it celery to run background tasks.

Packages:

1. celery==4.2.1
2. Django==2.1.3
3. Python==3.5
4. Redis-server==3.0.6

Configuration of celery in **settings.py** file is:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
            'task': 'app.tasks.task_number_one',
            'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}
```

And **celery.py** file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.prod')

app = Celery('project')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

When I run : `celery -A project worker -l info -B -E`

It points to rabmmitmq server, instead it should point to redis-server, shown below:

```
 -------------- celery@user-desktop v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.15.0-39-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic 2018-11-21 12:04:51
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         project:0x7f8b80f78d30
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . app.tasks.task_number_one
  . project.celery.debug_task

[2018-11-21 12:04:51,741: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
```

The same happend in production enviornment.
In production I have deployed the Django application with Gunicorn and Nginx, and now I want to implement some method to run background tasks, as `django-crontab` package is not working.

> Problem:
>
> 1. What is the problem with celery configuration?
> 2. Could anyone please recommend a method to run periodic background task?

**Note: I have tried implementing supervisor, but it seems supervisor is not compatible with python3, and therefore could not configure it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The setting for the [broker url changed in v4](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings).  It should be `BROKER_URL` and not `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: If you are using celery with django, then you need the `CELERY_` prefix. See https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#latentcall-django-admonition

Answer (score 8):

If you have copied the content of `celery.py` from the celery official website `https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html`

try changing following line, from

`app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')`

to

`app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='')`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  Not sure why removing namespace would fix it...

Answer (score 4):

Replace 
`CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'` with 
`BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

after changing `BROKER_URL` TO `CELERY_BROKER_URL` have to change this line in `celery.py`

```
app = Celery('proj')
```

add `'backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://'` so it looks like this

```
app = Celery('proj', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://')
```

now it will work **:)**

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was using the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` as the env variable to set the rediss endpoint and creating the Django settings `CELERY_BROKER_URL` with it

```
if is_env_var_set("CELERY_BROKER_URL"):
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = (
        "rediss://" +
        os.getenv("CELERY_BROKER_ENDPOINT") +
        ":6379" + "/0" +
        "?ssl_cert_reqs=required"
    )
else:
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

setting env variable

```
export CELERY_BROKER_URL="xyz.redis.region.oci.oraclecloud.com"
```

This was causing the celery to use `amqp` scheme instead of defined `rediss` scheme.

`CELERY_BROKER_URL` is the special env variable that is used by celery, using this variable for injecting redis endpoint caused this difficult to debug issue.

**Solution**

```
if is_env_var_set("CELERY_BROKER_ENDPOINT"):
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = (
        # note the rediss:// instead of redis:// to use SSL
        "rediss://" +
        os.getenv("CELERY_BROKER_ENDPOINT") +
        ":6379" + "/0" +
        "?ssl_cert_reqs=required"
    )
else:
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have redis as broker with .delay() method for queing tasks and got strange connection error 111 refusing connection to rabbitmq (which you don't use at all) try to use .apply_async()

This behavior happens in production.