# Django celery error while adding tasks to RabbitMQ message queue : AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, system-design

I have setup celery, rabbitmq and django web server on digitalocean. RabbitMQ runs on another server where my Django app is not running.
When I am trying to add the tasks to the queue using delay I am getting an error

> AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '**value**'

From django shell I am adding the task to my message queue.

**python3 manage.py shell**

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from app1.tasks import add
>>> add.delay(5, 6)
```

But getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 30, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 446, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 201, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Started celery as :

```
celery -A myproject worker -l info
```

which gives me

```
User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  warnings.warn(SecurityWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(

 -------------- celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.4.0-107-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2022-06-09 17:24:14
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myproject:0x7fd64fa5d970
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://himanshu:**@IPADDRESS2:5672/vhostcheck
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . app1.tasks.add

[2022-06-09 17:24:14,309: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://himanshu:**@IPADDRESS:5672/vhostcheck
[2022-06-09 17:24:14,313: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-06-09 17:24:15,333: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2022-06-09 17:24:15,349: WARNING/MainProcess] /etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py:70: UserWarning: A node named celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 is already using this process mailbox!


[2022-06-09 17:24:15,352: WARNING/MainProcess] /etc/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory

[2022-06-09 17:24:15,352: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 ready.
```

Inside app1 project :

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app1',
    'django_celery_results',
]

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://himanshu:password@IPADDRESS:5672/vhostcheck'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To ensure the app is loaded when Django starts, we need to import the Celery app we defined in `myproject/__init__.py`:

```
sudo nano myproject/__init__.py
```

```
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Comment: I assume that it should have been "we defined in myproject/__init.py__" instead of "we defined in myproject/init.py". 
Furthermore, according to your initial question and example, it should have been `__all__ = ['myproject']` instead of `__all__ = ['celery_app']`.
Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Kay I edited the answer with formatting so the dunders render correctly However, I'm not sure about the second part of your suggest since it is more substantive. I'm not taking the time right now to evaluate what the correct thing should be.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to add `broker_url` to my Django app settings. One way to do this is to create an environment variable named `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: this helped to figure my issue to find the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77735731/5305401 thanks Code-Apprentice